# Carousel doesn't show using the Actions on Google library integration

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

I am trying to show carousel getting the data from Firebase, Card works fine, but showing Carousel doesn't work but let conv = agent.conv(); is always Null. However I followed the instructions from here : [Using the Actions on Google library integration:](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/36). Please don't be mad, I am trying to learn.
Thanks

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient, Card} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const requestLib = require('request');
const {dialogflow, Carousel}= require('actions-on-google');
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

// Constant for image URLs
const IMG_URL_AOG = 'https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges' +
  '/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png';

// Constant for image URLs

const IMG_URL_GOOGLE_ALLO = 'https://allo.google.com/images/allo-logo.png';
const IMG_URL_GOOGLE_HOME = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com' +
  '/Nu3a6F80WfixUqf_ec_vgXy_c0-0r4VLJRXjVFF_X_CIilEu8B9fT35qyTEj_PEsKw';
const IMG_URL_GOOGLE_PIXEL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/madebygoog/v1' +
  '/Pixel/Pixel_ColorPicker/Pixel_Device_Angled_Black-720w.png';
const IMG_URL_MEDIA = 'http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/album_art.jpg';
const MEDIA_SOURCE = 'http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3';

// initialise DB connection
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
  // credential:admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
   databaseURL:'ws://test-catWorldXXXXX.com/'
});

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function handelModel (agent){

    const chosenModel = agent.parameters["toyota-models"].toLowerCase();
    let conv = agent.conv();

    if (chosenModel == "corolla") {

        return admin.database().ref('corolla').once("value")
        .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(model) {
        var value = model.val();
            agent.add("Nombre: " + value.nombre);
            Conv shows valor NULL...
            agent.add("conv " + conv); 

            conv.ask(new Carousel({
                items: {
                // Add the first item to the carousel
                [SELECTION_KEY_ONE]: {
      synonyms: [
        'synonym of title 1',
        'synonym of title 2',
        'synonym of title 3',
      ],
      title: 'Title of First Carousel Item',
      description: 'This is a description of a carousel item.',
      image: new Image({
        url: IMG_URL_AOG,
        alt: 'Image alternate text',
      }),
    },
                // Add the second item to the carousel
                [SELECTION_KEY_GOOGLE_HOME]: {
      synonyms: [
        'Google Home Assistant',
        'Assistant on the Google Home',
    ],
      title: 'Google Home',
      description: 'Google Home is a voice-activated speaker powered by ' +
        'the Google Assistant.',
      image: new Image({
        url: IMG_URL_GOOGLE_HOME,
        alt: 'Google Home',
      }),
    },
                // Add third item to the carousel
                [SELECTION_KEY_GOOGLE_PIXEL]: {
                synonyms: [
            'Google Pixel XL',
            'Pixel',
            'Pixel XL',
          ],
                title: 'Google Pixel',
                description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
                image: new Image({
            url: IMG_URL_GOOGLE_PIXEL,
            alt: 'Google Pixel',
          }),
            },
                // Add last item of the carousel
                [SELECTION_KEY_GOOGLE_ALLO]: {
                title: 'Google Allo',
                synonyms: [
                'Allo',
                ],
                description: 'Introducing Google Allo, a smart messaging app that ' +
                'helps you say more and do more.',
                image: new Image({
                url: IMG_URL_GOOGLE_ALLO,
                alt: 'Google Allo Logo',
                }),
            },
        },
    }));
            agent.add(conv);
        });
        });
  }
    else {
        return admin.database().ref('yaris').once("value")
        .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(model) {
            var value = model.val();
            const a11yText = 'Google Assistant Bubbles';
            const googleUrl = 'https://google.com';

                title: value.nombre,
                imageUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant.png',
                text: 'This is the body text of a card.  You can even use line\n  breaks and emoji! ',
                buttonText: 'This is a button',
                buttonUrl: 'https://assistant.google.com/'
            })
            );
        });
    });
  }
}

    // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
 let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('ask-models', handelModel);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found something on this issue https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/37#issuecomment-437036370:

> Like jorgecasar pointed out, you need to set the agent.requestSource,
>   otherwise, agent.conv() return null

```
const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
agent.requestSource = agent.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE;
```

> then agent.conv() would not return null

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to test this with the Dialogflow tester on the right margin.

If you're looking to test Action on Google responses, you should be testing with the Actions on Google simulator.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Prisoner I don't want this to work only for google assistant however I test it and I get this error "parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response."